# How to play next song on completion of a song?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create a media player. For that I am trying to play next song on completion of previous one. Here is my code:

```
int i = 0;

public void track(View view) {
    while (!m1.isPlaying()) {
        play(list.get(i));
        while (m1.isPlaying()) ;
            i++;
    }
}

public void play(String T) {
    try {
        m1.setDataSource(T);
        m1.prepare();
        m1.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please mark an answer as accepted answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `setOnCompletionListener`. This allows you to get a callback from the `MediaPlayer` when the playback is finished. You can start the next track in there:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
        //play next track
        play(mNextTrack);
    }
})
```

See [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) for more details.